# How to query SVN server for users who logged on in the past X days?

Tags: svn

Is there a SVN command that will tell me what users logged on in the past X days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Logging on" is not an action that subversion supports.  You could mangle something together by looking at commits if you want.

```
svn log | grep "^r.*<Date spec>"
```

Where `<Date spec>` is going to be something that matches the date range you want.  So `"^r.*Jun 2014"` would match all the commits in June and `"^r.* 1[0-9] May 2014"` matches all the commits between the 10th and 19th of May.  A regex that matches the last ten days would be different every day so that sounds messy.

The subversion server will also have logs and depending on how long you're keeping these logs before rotating, you will be able to see all actions any user has performed in whatever logs you have.

Here's an example using `mod_dav_svn` and the Apache logs:

```
192.168.0.1 - ladadadada [12/May/2014:16:20:53 +0000] "OPTIONS /repo/trunk HTTP/1.1" 200 996 "-" "SVN/1.6.17 (r1128011) neon/0.28.6"
192.168.0.1 - ladadadada [12/May/2014:16:38:59 +0000] "PUT /repo/!svn/wrk/2de09554-002f-4c20-9305-308efcba7ded/trunk/application/config/functions.php HTTP/1.1" 204 149 "-" "SVN/1.6.17 (r1128011) neon/0.28.6"
192.168.0.1 - ladadadada [12/May/2014:16:39:00 +0000] "MERGE /repo/trunk/application/config HTTP/1.1" 200 676 "-" "SVN/1.6.17 (r1128011) neon/0.28.6"
192.168.0.1 - ladadadada [12/May/2014:16:39:00 +0000] "DELETE /repo/!svn/act/2de09554-002f-4c20-9305-308efcba7ded HTTP/1.1" 204 149 "-" "SVN/1.6.17 (r1128011) neon/0.28.6"
```

The user is the third field and the actions being performed are the method of the HTTP request.  This means you can see actions like `svn update` and `svn log` as well as commits.  If you rotate your logs daily then the last ten days is simply a matter of grepping through the most recent ten log files.